# Automapper ignore first source field letter

Tags: c#, automapper

I am mapping database entities to objects with automapper. Fields in database entities are named like x_name and I would like to map those to object without that 'X' prefix ("name" in this case).

So objects are something like:

```
public class EntityModel
{
    public string x_name;
}


public class MappingDest
{
    public string name;
}
```

Sure I could use MapFrom()- method for those fields, but as there are quite many of them it would be handy to just say something like "ignore first letter from source to all members".

Is this possible with Automapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{            
    cfg.RecognizePrefixes("x_");
});
```

`RecognizePrefixes` takes a `string[]` so you can pass all of your prefixes you have.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed :)